# amsart and titlesec - title font won't change

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec, amsart

Ok, I am very new to LaTeX. I am using a default template. I have been trying to figure out how to change the font sizes and other formatting. Reading forums convinced me to try `titlesec`. All `titlesec` formatting is added to the template (which I don't really understand). The section headings will change size - but not the title. It stays at 12pt. And why is it in all caps? I think it has something to do with `amsart`, but I could really use some help. My setup looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. 
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedright}
\titleformat {\title}
  {\normalfont \HUGE \bfseries \justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat {\section}
  {\normalfont \large \bfseries \justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat {\subsection}
  {\normalfont \large \bfseries \justifyheading}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\title{Recall Some Preliminaries}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Tensor Calculus}
%\subsection{}

whatever

\end{document}
```

The section headings will change size - but not the title. It stays at 12pt.

Comment: @egreg: any particular reason for not accepting my edit (which was essentially the same as yours)?

Comment: @Koji I didn't reject any edit.

Comment: Notice that `\HUGE` does not exist, the largest font command is `\Huge`.

Comment: @egreg: my bad, then. Probably nearly simultaneous or something.

Comment: Since you're trying to get the `article` shape, use `\documentclass{article}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\title` cannot be modified using `titlesec` package. I think that easiest solution is to make title by yourself, using the `center` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. 
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedright}
\titleformat {\section}
  {\normalfont \large \bfseries \justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat {\subsection}
  {\normalfont \large \bfseries \justifyheading}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\title{Recall Some Preliminaries}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{3ex minus 1ex}
\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\shorttitle}
\end{center}
\vskip 5ex minus 1ex

\section*{Tensor Calculus}
%\subsection{}

whatever

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah-ha! Ok that did it. Thankyou very much. I will use this.

Comment: @Lex In that case, you might consider accepting the answer using the tick mark at the top-left of the answer ;)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks - I will remember to do that from here on.